# Topolgy vs simple features

Tags: postgis, topology, sf

I'm starting using PostGIS, and then I found the main extensions of it, Simple Features (postgis), Topology (postgis_topology), Rasters(postgis_raster).

The Topology extension is great, in some aspects too great, everything with a structure or nodes match pretty well with it, but, after thinking a while..., every simple features con be considered a topology.

Like, geopolitical, the limits from one country to other, are more the type of topology than sf, because they are connected, and related, is pretty important the limit from one country match and be the same as the other side, a "series of nodes" that delimit the space.

So, when not to use topology? That is one of the questions, when to use topology and when sf?

Someone may say, use SF when you are storing not related/connected features, and I can say, "if there is not connected features, I can always made new groups that are related and made new topologies with it, so, every data inside that is related", that is right, if I make groups with related spatial data, every collection can be set in a topology db, so in the end, when should I use SF?

Comment: I would say that topology is theoretically much better but also more complicated. Features without topology became common when ArcView was introduced if not earlier. For many use cases, like rendering a map, these independent "shapes" are good enough. Maintaining topology of a coverages made from independent polygons by applying rules "polygons must not overlap", "polygons must not have gaps" when the architecture actually allows them to overlap and have gaps is painful.